# How to handle Browser level authentication in Karate UI?

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I tried to login into our test website, which has browser level authentication. Normally dealing with Login UI we can send the email and password through input method, but in login popup I am not sure how to send email and password to the field.

I have went through the below answer
[Handling Basic Authentication in Karate UI scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60333071/handling-basic-authentication-in-karate-ui-scenario)
But couldn't get any clue, is there any simpler way to implement this using Karate.

Here is the screenshot for the Login pop-up.

[image: Login]

Comment: nothing to do with karate, see this please: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44542740/143475

Comment: Is there any way to handle this in Karate or Selenium will be more suitable?

Comment: based on all the questions you have asked so far I think selenium would be more suitable for you